# Web Form get links to function

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I am using a code I got online, and modified. It makes a web form from a google sheet. The problem I am coming into is with links. I have links in a few of the cells and when deployed it just brings in the text of the link but it is not a functional link. Can someone direct me?

Google app script:

```
    function doGet(e) {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DisplaySheet');
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}

function getSheetData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Single Job View');
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getDataRange();
  var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();
  return dataValues;
}
```

and the HTML script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }

      td {
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
      }

      td.empty {
        border: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Display Google Sheet Web App</h1>
    <table>
      <? var tableData = getSheetData(); ?>
      <? for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) { ?>
        <tr>
          <? for (var j = 0; j < tableData[i].length; j++) { ?>
            <? var cellValue = tableData[i][j]; ?>
            <? var cellClass = cellValue ? '' : 'empty'; ?>
            <td class="<?= cellClass ?>"><pre><?= cellValue ?></pre></td>
          <? } ?>
        </tr>
      <? } ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your script and question, I thought that in your situation, it is required to retrieve both the values and the hyperlinks from the cells. So, how about modifying your script as follows?

#### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DisplaySheet');
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}

function getSheetData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Single Job View');
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getDataRange();
  var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();
  var links = dataRange.getRichTextValues().map(r => r.map(c => c.getLinkUrl() || null));
  var html = dataValues.map((r, i) =>
    "<tr>" + r.map((c, j) => {
      const link = links[i][j];
      const h = link ? `<a href="${link}"><pre>${c}</pre></a>` : `<pre>${c}</pre>`;
      return `<td class="${c}">${h}</td>`;
    }).join("") + "</tr>"
  ).join("");
  return html;
}
```

#### HTML side:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }

      td {
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
      }

      td.empty {
        border: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Display Google Sheet Web App</h1>
    <table><?!= getSheetData() ?></table>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Note:

- From [this benchmark (Author: me)](https://tanaikech.github.io/2022/06/07/benchmark-process-cost-for-html-template-using-google-apps-script/), I put the HTML table in your HTML template by creating it at Google Apps Script side.
- In this modification, it supposes that a link is put to a cell. Please be careful about this.
- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### References:

- [getRichTextValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrichtextvalues)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. Now I just need to get a working drop down that changes a cell on my google sheet and Im done

Comment: @John Velella Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too. About your future goal, if you have a question and post it as a new question, I would like to check it.

Comment: I did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76546486/google-web-app-form-text-wrap-and-drop-down-updating-the-google-sheet-problems