# Google Web app Form text wrap and drop down updating the google sheet problems

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, webforms

So I have a web form, It is something I am going to give to my clients so they can see the status of each job I am doing for them. with help from StackI have it working but there are 2 new hurdles. In one of the cells there is a lot of data (job notes) and the text doesn't wrap and just make the cell box lower automatically (CSS problem I think) And I need it to have a drop down list that is all the jobs, so they can pick the job and have it update the form. Right now I have to change the drop down on the actual sheet. I'll link the sheet if anyone wants to see.

```
The codes so far:
 function doGet(e) {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DisplaySheet');
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}

function getSheetData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Single Job View');
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getDataRange();
  var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();
  var links = dataRange.getRichTextValues().map(r => r.map(c => c.getLinkUrl() || null));
  var html = dataValues.map((r, i) =>
    "<tr>" + r.map((c, j) => {
      const link = links[i][j];
      const cellClass = c === "" ? "empty" : ""; // Add "empty" class for blank cells
      const h = link ? `<a href="${link}"><pre>${c}</pre></a>` : `<pre>${c}</pre>`;
      return `<td class="${cellClass}">${h}</td>`;
    }).join("") + "</tr>"
  ).join("");
  return html;
}
```

and the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        background-image: url("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1LtKxyqufn8PcIidJ9SbZnIKHojkDLLvv");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
      }

      td {
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      td.empty {
        border: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>National Supplments</h1>
    <table><?!= getSheetData() ?></table>
  </body>
</html>
```

The list of address's is on "All Jobs info" tab and I have a middle tab "Single Data" that is used to sort the data down to one job for the tab that the web form uses.

Link to the web form: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz4gXvKw_ksAVQf4ilDuG24jkKtsQ4BUNmgwlVozt96CXLuJ0IDxZJ8ojgslgb9ortV/exec

Link to the google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11JirF-0T3K7xvDryLlbI98n0fSh_DiWB42EJ_qWz8Qk/edit#gid=2055655488

Comment: I might try putting a text area in that cell so they can resize it if they wish

Comment: Also, anyone know why I can't use safari to open the web form, or even the app script editor, just never lets me and I have to switch over to chrome to make either of those work

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your expected situation from your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: So the "Single Data" Tab on the linked sheet is what it is supposed to be like but in a web form. The cell A1 is a drop down that changes the  data below. The web form gets all the data that is updated from the  "Single Job View". It was easier for me to filter the sheet this way. I am open to easier solutions.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still imagine your expected situation. When I could correctly imagine your expected result, I think that I can propose a modified script. But, unfortunately, I cannot still do it. I apologize for this. But, I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly imagine it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: If you open the spreadsheet from the link I provided, I made a new tab called "Mock up" that tab has 2 photos, one on the left that is how it should look, and one on the right how it should not. Let me know if that makes sense now. Thank you for any help

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `When I switched address and reloaded the table was made much wider. It doesnt auto resize and just wrap the text. This makes it so it is much harder to view. To see this yourself you can change the green drop down on the "Single Data" tab and see it does not fit well with the "111" address, but it fits great with the "222" address.` in your updated Spreadsheet. But, when I could correctly understand your question, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: As I understand, you want to visualize the table with a specific size (width) and wrap the text when needed, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, problem is right now many times the test in the "Notes" section just keeps running well off the screen to the right and it's annoying to have to scroll over that far.